# Daily Apache log file upload to oracle database using PHP/Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, oracle, apache

I am generating daily Apache log files. Now i need to insert this file data to oracle database on daily basis. I wrote a code for uploading file to database manually for one file. However i need a script/code which will pick the file automatically from the location or just increase the filename by date and then insert data into database(My filename is by date which is changing daily. Example : access.2018.07.24.txt). Can someone please assist.

```html
<?php
$conn = oci_connect('usr1', 'dfdfdf1SS', 'sdsdfdg/XEBH');
if (!$conn) {
   $m = oci_error();
   echo $m['message'], "\n";
   exit;
}
else {
   print "Connected to Oracle!";
   }
$myfile = fopen("access.2018.07.24.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
while(!feof($myfile)) {
 $content= fgets($myfile);
 $carray=explode(',',$content);
 list($IP_ADDRESS, $USER_IDENTIFIER, $USERID , $REQUEST_TIME , $CLIENT_REQUEST ,$RESPONSE_CODE ,$SIZEOFOBJECT, $COOKIES)=$carray;
 

 $stdii = 'INSERT INTO LOGS(IP_ADDRESS, USER_IDENTIFIER, USERID , REQUEST_TIME , CLIENT_REQUEST ,RESPONSE_CODE ,SIZEOFOBJECT, COOKIES)'.
 'values(:IP_ADDRESS, :USER_IDENTIFIER, :USERID , :REQUEST_TIME , :CLIENT_REQUEST ,:RESPONSE_CODE ,:SIZEOFOBJECT, :COOKIES)';
 $compiled1 = oci_parse($conn, $stdii);
 oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':IP_ADDRESS', $IP_ADDRESS);
 oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':USER_IDENTIFIER', $USER_IDENTIFIER);
 oci_bind_by_name($compiled1,':USERID', $USERID);
 oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':REQUEST_TIME', $REQUEST_TIME);
 oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':CLIENT_REQUEST', $CLIENT_REQUEST);
 oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':RESPONSE_CODE', $RESPONSE_CODE);
 oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':SIZEOFOBJECT', $SIZEOFOBJECT);
 oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':COOKIES', $COOKIES);
 oci_execute($compiled1, OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);
}
oci_close($conn);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Comment: Although I would start by keeping a log of all the logs that have been processed which you check first, so if the script fails for a few days and nobody notices (it will happen) A restart will get all the missing files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the DateTime class in PHP you can do it like this. I am assuming for this example you want yesterdays date in the filename

```
$d = new DateTime();
$yesterday = $d->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'))->format('Y.m.d');
$filename = "access.$yesterday.txt";

echo $filename;
```

RESULT (run on 24/7/2018)

```
access.2018.07.23.txt
```

Then use `$filename` in the fopen call like this

```
$myfile = fopen($filename, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help RiggsFolly . I tried this but i am not sure how to pass this as argument while opening the file." $myfile = fopen($filename, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");"

Comment: I added that to the answer

Comment: You did remove the `echo $filename;` from my example didn't you?

Comment: yes, i removed it. Your code is working fine. I made some mistake in my filename(it was access.<date>.log).I did the correction and its opening the file. But now i have some errors in my array. list($IP_ADDRESS, $USER_IDENTIFIER, $USERID , $REQUEST_TIME , $CLIENT_REQUEST ,$RESPONSE_CODE ,$SIZEOFOBJECT, $COOKIES)=$carray;     Error: Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in C:\wamp64\www\db_conn\logs1.php on line 20

Comment: Looks like your apache access log does not look like you thought. Also note that not all lines in an access log always follow the same format. You are going to have to check the line and its format when you read it, then output what is actually on that line

Comment: thanks much. i changed my log file format today and changed the code accordingly. But in this code i was fetching yesterday's file which was in different format. Thanks for the help everything is working fine now. :)